# Returning json result separated by new line

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am creating web service using asp.net web api application and I am returning the result in json format which looks like

```
[{"Name":"xxxxx","Age":"10"},{"Name":"yyyy","Age":"20"},{"Name":"zzzzz","Age":"30"}]
```

But I want output like

```
{"Name":"xxxxx","Age":"10"}
{"Name":"yyyy","Age":"20"}
{"Name":"zzzzz","Age":"30"}
```

Can any one tell me how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

This is my code

```
 public class Example
    {

        List<ResultData> resultdata = new List<ResultData>();

        public List<ResultData> Records(String value)
        {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from tablename where column=" +value + " LIMIT 1000");

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.FetchSize = int.MaxValue;

            SqlResultSet result = reader.FetchResult();


            foreach (SqlRecord row in result)
            {

                resultdata.Add(new ResultData() { Name = row[0].ToString(),Age = row[1].ToString() });


            }

            return resultdata;

        }

}
```

My webapiconfig.cs looks like this

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.
           SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
    }
}
```

Also I tried to return a string like json string but it fails in which I have escaped double quotes but quotes with escaped symbol is returned in the result

Comment: The first is an array of objects and the second is just three distinct objects. Can you post the code that does this so that readers can better guide you? Also, is the return for displayed output or is it for variables? Provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, why do want to do this? You get an array of objects, but you want to return 3 object (root nodes) in one response, which is not possible.

Maybe [these](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml) guidelines help.